# How to deploy the react app on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Ubuntu virtual server through AWS on ec2. I have started the app and was able to access it through localhost:8080, but when I tried to visit outside the server it says: `Refused to Connect`. I have opened ports 8080 and 80 in the security groups. Is there something else I should do? Unfortunately I think i destroyed the instance messing with the iptables so I won't be able to provide any config info.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it will be one file,because React will be compiled.
I'm sure that the file is named bundle.js.

if you import that file into a HTML file with the script tag, React will work.

You must open the port :80 and set the document root.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use nginx or apache to proxy pass 80 to 8080.

1. Install apache
2. go to httpd.conf
3. set Virtual host like this:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyRequests Off
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. same you can do for https, proxy pass 443 to 8443 or whatever port you run your react app.